# Appending another list of csv values to another column

Tags: python, arrays, xml-parsing

I am trying to append the another row of values in another column. this is my first time doing python and I have referenced a few articles however I did not manage to get it to work.

Below are my code snippets as you can see `savetoCSV()` writes to the file then `saveQIDtoCSV()` appends to it.

I am trying to achieve the following output, values in 2 separate columns.

```
Name       ID
```

My code:

```
def savetoCSV(detectionItems,filename):

    # specifying the fields for csv file
    fields = ['HOST_LIST', 'DATETIME', 'QID', 'IP', 'TRACKING_METHOD', 'media']
    lstdetectionItems=[detectionItems]
    #lstQID = [qid]
    # writing to csv file
    with open(filename, 'w' , newline= '') as csvfile:

        # creating a csv dict writer object
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter='\n')

        for qid in lstdetectionItems:
            writer.writerows(lstdetectionItems)

def saveQIDtoCSV(qid, filename):

    # specifying the fields for csv file
    fields = ['HOST_LIST', 'DATETIME', 'QID', 'IP', 'TRACKING_METHOD', 'media']
    lstdetectionItems=[qid]

    # writing to csv file
    with open(filename, 'a' , newline= '') as csvfile:

        # creating a csv dict writer object
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')

        for qid in lstdetectionItems:
                f1= open(filename,'r')
                reader=csv.reader(f1)
                for row in reader:
                        row[1] = f1.readline()
                        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "to append the another row of values in another column"? What is the soruce of the `Name` and `ID` values?

Comment: it world be easy if you use pandas

Comment: the source of the name and ID values will be from an xml file element

Comment: what i mean by append is that i am trying to write another set of values into another column which is Name in one column and the values of ID in another column